# Displaying form data to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is My [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aH6hb/)

After Filling the form and clicking add button, i want the form data to be displayed inside the table. can someone help me how can i do it with jquery.

```
<div class="form-div">
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Item Details</legend>
        <label>Enter Item Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <select class="input-mini">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn">Add Data</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div class="table-div">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> S.no </th>
            <th> Item Name </th>
            <th> Quantity </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything out yet? I don't see any jQuery in your fiddle either.

Comment: Actually i don't know how to get form data. i just know doing $('.table > tbody:last').append('<tr>...</tr>'); would append the data. but i am not sure what to write inside

Comment: Rajesh has a great answer - study it until you understand every line. (The purpose of the `return false` is to stop the button from submitting the form). Tiago Alves also has a good point: use IDs to address (select) each element specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give unique identifiers to the elements you want to manipulate. After that you can do something like this using `click()`, `val()` and `append()` jQuery functions:

```
var sno = 0;
$("form button.btn").click(function() {
    var item_name = $("#item_name").val();
    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    var new_row = "<tr><td>" + ++sno + "</td><td>" + item_name + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(new_row);
    return false;
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH6hb/1/)

Better give a `ID` to `form` and `table` elements if they are not unique in the window and also to optimize DOM selections.

Comment: i want the value of the form to be cleared after the value gets added to table row. can you suggest how to do that

Comment: @user2847429 yes. do this in the end: `$("#item_name, #quantity").val("");` See this: http://jsfiddle.net/aH6hb/6/

Comment: +1 Wow, I had never seen string concatenation and incremental operator at the same time. `+ ++sno +` looks so odd, but I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Wrote the code and added fiddle.

You need to get values of `text` and `select` and create a new row, then add to `tbody`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aH6hb/2/

Comment: I used jQuery library. And `trim()` removes leading and trailing white space from the gievn string.

Comment: No. `$.trim()` does not override default `String.trim()`.

Comment: That is the way to call functions defined within jQuery

Comment: *Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code*. How did you bypass that?

Comment: I did not bypass. My answer has code, if you can see closely. :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<div class="">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Item Details</legend>
            <label>Enter Item Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" id="item_name">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <select class="input-mini" id="quentity">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn" onclick="viewRecord()">Add Data</button>
        </fieldset>

</div>
<div class="">
    <table class="table controls controls-row">
        <thead>
            <tr id="heading">
                <th> S.no </th>
                <th> Item Name </th>
                <th> Quantity </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

js part

```
var index=0;
function viewRecord(){
    index++;
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+index+'</td><td>'+$("#item_name").val()+' </td><td> '+$("#quentity option:selected").val()+'</td></tr>');
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aH6hb/4/)**